# checking the value of an array returned by a foreach statement

Tags: php

here's my code:

```
<?php

$class = array();
/*$class = array_reverse($class_model, false);*/

$cycle = 199 ;
$i= 0;

$contentdirectory = 'DEADWAVE_proj_dir/DEAD-WAVE_content/';     
$contentlaunch = scandir($contentdirectory);
natsort($contentlaunch);        
$id = count($contentlaunch); 

foreach ( $contentlaunch as $value )
{ 
  if ( preg_match("/.png",$value)
       || preg_match("/.jpg",$value)
       || preg_match("/.gif",$value) )
   {
    echo '<a id="'.--$id.'"target="_blank" href="">
       <img  class="'.$class[ $i % $cycle ].'"
       src="DEADWAVE_proj_dir/DEAD-WAVE_content/'.$value.'"/></a>';
    ++$i;
   }
 }
```

?>

this simply doesn't work, the question is why.

I imagined that it would work to check the file type and echo img tags for only those array values that are images avoiding the non image files in the directory.  I'm open to every solution.

Comment: this example is rather confusing. i don't fully understand what it's trying to do. in your loop, you're decrementing $i and then incrementing it on the next statement. why are you doing that?

Comment: the class array is empty, and your line formatting is difficult to follow, try to make your code as clear and concise as possible for us to better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$class = array();

$class = array_reverse($class_model, false);
$cycle = 199 ;
$i = 0;

$contentdirectory = 'DEADWAVE_proj_dir/DEAD-WAVE_content/'; 
$contentlaunch = scandir($contentdirectory);

natsort($contentlaunch);
foreach ( $contentlaunch as $id => $value ) 
{   
    if ( preg_match("/(\/.png|\/.jpg|\/.gif)/",$value) ) 
    {
        echo '<a id="'.$id.'" target="_blank" href=""><img class="'.$class[ $i++ % $cycle ].'"  src="DEADWAVE_proj_dir/DEAD-WAVE_content/'.$value.'"/></a>';  
    } 
} 
?>
```

note: I would not use this method to check for imagess, but brian_d method:

```
if ( in_array(pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), array('jpg', 'gif', 'png')) ) { ...
```

finally, I'm not sure about all the $class/$cycle stuff...

Answer (score 0):

To find out if a file is an image, you may use:

```
// $path = 'somepath';
// $filename = 'somefile';
$finfo = new finfo();
$currentFileMimeType = $finfo->file($path . $filename, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if('image' == array_shift((explode('/', $currentFileMimeType))))
{
    // echo images
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex patterns will not work. For instance,  `"/.png"` should be `/\.png/`

Instead of using regex though, you could just use the function [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) which will give you the file extension for a given path.

```
$info = pathinfo($value);
$extension = $info['extension'];
if (in_array($extension, array('png', 'jpg', 'gif')) {
  ..
```